# Java inline method that contains private calls

Tags: java, jvm, inline, private

Assuming that the jvm identifies the b.foo() method as hot, will it try to inline it? Because if it does, the call instruction B.bar() will be inlined in the A.main method, which is prohibited because bar is private. What does the jvm do in these situations?

Any documentation with further details is appreciated as well. Thanks

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        for (int i=0; i<99999; i++)
            b.foo();
    }
}

class B {

    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    private void bar() { // do something. (is small method)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm asking because when i try to do this optimization myself (in bytecode) I get a verify error which makes sense:

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad invokespecial instruction: current class isn't assignable to reference class

EDIT2:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=5, args_size=1
     0: new           #13                 // class B
     3: dup
     4: invokespecial #14                 // Method B."<init>":()V
     7: astore_1
     8: iconst_0
     9: istore_2
    10: iload_2
    11: ldc           #15                 // int 99999
    13: if_icmpge     30
    16: aload_1
    17: astore        4
    19: aload         4
    21: invokespecial #18                 // Method B.bar:()V // VERIFY ERROR HERE
    24: iinc          2, 1
    27: goto          10
    30: return
  StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
    frame_type = 253 /* append */
      offset_delta = 10
      locals = [ class B, int ]
    frame_type = 19 /* same */
  LineNumberTable:
    line 5: 0
    line 6: 8
    line 7: 16
    line 14: 19
    line 15: 24
    line 6: 24
    line 8: 30
```

Comment: Why do you think it is prohibited to inline private methods?

Comment: the foo method that is inlined is not private, it's public

Comment: Can you show the bytecode you've produced that causes the VerifyError?

Comment: @DavidConrad Done

Comment: Uh, if it inlined bar into foo, and foo into main, it would insert the instructions that *make up* bar into main. It wouldn't insert a *call to bar* in main.

Comment: Yes, if bar is a candidate for inline. In general though it might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. in the beginning, there is source code
2. the java compiler turns it into bytecode
3. the jvm reads the bytecode, verifies its integrity, and interprets it. The bytecode of "hot spots" (frequently executed blocks of code) is just-in-time compiled into the instruction set of the CPU the JVM is running on

In Java, most optimization is deferred to the JIT-compiler in step 3 to benefit from statistics gathered during program execution. This includes inlining.

Access modifiers such as `private` are checked during verification, before the bytecode is interpreted, and before it is JIT-compiled. Since access modifiers have already been checked, the JIT is totally agnostic of their existence, and inlining a private method causes no difficulty.

BTW, if you want to check what the JIT does, you can use hotspot's [`-XX:+PrintAssembly`](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PrintAssembly) to have the machine code translated back into assembly code for your inspection.

Comment: Actually, the JIT compiler is not “totally” agnostic to access modifiers, as it is important whether a target method could be overridden. In that regard, a `private` method is even *easier* to inline, as it can’t be overridden. Though, in most other cases, there are ways to still inline overridable methods, like in the OP’s example code where a) the target is the result of the `new` operator, b) the method is invoked on the same object within a loop and c) no subclass of `B` exists anyway, and each of these three points alone would be sufficient to enable inlining.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the optimizations are usually done at the JVM level.  At runtime, the JVM perform some "complicated" analysis to determine which methods to inline.  It can be aggressive in inlining, and the Hotspot JVM actually can inline non-final methods.

The java compilers almost never inline any method call (the JVM does all of that at runtime).   They do inline compile time constants (e.g. final static primitive values).  But not methods.

For more resources:

1. [Article: The Java HotSpot Performance Engine: Method Inlining Example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#method)
2. [Wiki: Inlining in OpenJDK](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Inlining), not fully populated but contains links to useful discussions.